# Can I bundle Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool (.diagcab) files with my software?

Tags: windows, license, diagnostic

I am having difficulty finding any licenses of these files. Provided I don't modify, only call them, am I allowed to distribute them alongside my other software?

EDIT: The tool I want to use: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

As far as I know it's not included in Windows, and there is no passkey required. It also doesn't have copyright info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft support and apparently there is no license, and I am allowed to redistribute it without modifications.

Answer (score 2):

#### Am I allowed to distribute them alongside my other software?

Why would you want to? It already included in:

> Windows 10/8, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

In addition, the Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool requires a passkey to open the tool:

> When you contact Microsoft Support for any help, the support professional will give you a Passkey. You are required to open the Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool and enter the Passkey.

How do you plan to run it without the required passkey?

Source [How to run Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool in Windows 7/8/10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-microsoft-support-diagnostic-tool-in-windows-7)

The copyright for MSDT belongs to Microsoft so distribution is not allowed without their permission.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the question with what exactly I want to use. It doesn't have copyright info, and doesn't need a passkey.

Comment: The download page doesn't give you permission to redistribute, so don't do that.

Comment: As far as I can see it doesn't prohibit it either, and there's the "If you’re not on the computer that has the problem... " part which implies copying it is fine. 

You'd think that company like Microsoft would attach proper licenses to their products.

Comment: *shrug* we are not lawyers and your question is probably off-topic anyway. You should ask Microsoft for a definitive answer.

Comment: I contacted Microsoft support and apparently there is no license, and I am allowed to redistribute it without modifications. Well... _shrug_

Comment: Then you can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).